# 2-letter abbreviation for the name Montgomery

Tags: abbreviations, names, nicknames

Background:

I'm implementing elliptic curve cryptography in a hobbyist project of mine. And two kinds of the curves I'm about implement are Edwards curve and Montgomery curve ([this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8032/) and [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748)).

For the [SEC#2](https://secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf) curves, they're of prime order, so I prefixed the name of the subroutines for them with `ecp_` which stands for "Elliptic Curve of Prime order". As for Edwards curve, they're already used in EdDSA digital signature scheme, so I can use the prefix `ecEd_`.

I think the "Mont-" part of the name Montgomery can be abbreviated into 2 letters, but I'm not sure about this etymologically, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ancestry.co.uk](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/name-origin?surname=montgomery) gives an etymology:

> English, Scottish, and northern Irish (of Norman origin): habitational name from a place in Calvados, France, so named from Old French *mont* ‘hill’ + a Germanic personal name composed of the elements *guma* ‘man’ + *ric* ‘power’.

Since *Mt* is a customary abbreviation for the cognate English word *Mount* where it appears in names (eg "Mt Everest", "Mt St Helens") I'd suggest *Mt* provides what you want.